# How can I get access to the rowData of my datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I try to access to the "rowData" of my datatables row:

```
  $('.table').on( 'row-reordered.dt', function ( e, diff, edit ) {
    console.log( table.row( this ).data() );
  } );
```

But the output is:

```
undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`pre-row-reorder`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/pre-row-reorder) event to get the node index for the row you are dragging - and you can then use the index to get the row's data:

```
  $('.table').on( 'pre-row-reorder', function ( e, node, index ) {
    console.log( "row index: " + node.index);
    console.log( table.row(node.index).data() ); // the row's data
  } );
```

Depending on how you originally populated your table, this will return an array `[...]`, or an object `{...}` containing the row's data.

Comment: what can I do when I need the rows data in the row-reordered function?

Comment: To do that you can use the technique in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63115844/datatable-row-reorder-completion-not-getting-updated-row-id/63118856#63118856). That tells you the row index of the moved row, after the move has been completed. Then you can use that to access the row's data: `console.log( table.row(diff[i].newPosition).data() );`.

Comment: One point to note: If you drag a row too far (outside the draggable range - i.e. outside the table) you may get unexpected results. The events still appear to fire, even though the row does not actually move.

Comment: Ah no, it does not work. Because like this I can get the rowData of the row that I am moving but still I need the rowData of the the others that are changing the position

Comment: That approach gives you all those rows - that's the data inside the `diff` variable. It's just that in that specific code sample, I only use the original row, because that answered the specific question. Look at the loop - it iterates across the full set of changed rows. That should give you the data you need.

Comment: And just to add: If you want every change (provided by the `diff` data) then you don't need the `pre-row-reorder` event - because it sounds like you don't need to handle the actively moved row differently from the other rows which moved as a consequence of the actively moved row. So you can simplify that part of the solution.

Comment: The problem is, that I need for the "changed" rows in the row.reordered function this specific value  `table.row(node.index).data().uuid )` and this is only accessable in the pre-row-reorder function. Can you give me an example, because I do not know how you mean it

Comment: with `diff` I get different data, I do not have access to the uuid

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use the `edit` param as in:

```
$('.table').on( 'row-reordered.dt', function ( e, diff, edit ) {
  console.log( table.row(edit).data() );
});
```

try look at this http://jsfiddle.net/x3j7bq1w/

Comment: thank you! This works well. Only question, this is only giving me the result of the first row in my table, is it possible to get access to for example the second row?